# Qt remove nested layout

Tags: c++, qt

I've got several `QHBoxLayout` objects nested inside a single `QVBoxLayout`. I've looked through a number of stackoverflow questions and answers, but I've not been able to find a way to completely remove the layout for the contents of the `QScrollArea` widget. All the answers I've seen have only made it possible to set the layout again, but when the layout does get set a second time, the objects are still present.

This is the code that I'm working with:

```
QSignalMapper* sMap = new QSignalMapper(this);
QVBoxLayout* vBox = new QVBoxLayout();

outerVector = 0;
for (vector<vector<QPushButton*>>::iterator o_iter = buttonGrid.begin(); o_iter < buttonGrid.end(); o_iter++) {
    int innerVector = 0;
    QHBoxLayout* hBox = new QHBoxLayout();
    for (vector<QPushButton*>::iterator i_iter = (*o_iter).begin(); i_iter < (*o_iter).end(); i_iter++) {
        hBox->addWidget(buttonGrid.at(outerVector).at(innerVector));
        sMap->setMapping(buttonGrid.at(outerVector).at(innerVector), ((outerVector * 100) + innerVector));
        connect(buttonGrid.at(outerVector).at(innerVector), SIGNAL(clicked()), sMap, SLOT(map()));
        innerVector++;
    }
    vBox->addLayout(hBox);
    outerVector++;
}

ui->GameAreaWidgetContents->setLayout(vBox);
connect(sMap, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(on_buttonGrid_clicked(int)));
```

Right now, I have this for clearing the layout:

```
delete hBox;
delete vBox;
ui->GameAreaWidgetContents->layout();
```

What is the best, and most effective way to clear the contents of the widget?

Comment: Maybe you want `ui->GameAreaWidgetContents->layout()->findChildren<QWidget*>()` to get the list of child widgets that are part of the layout and delete the widgets in the list.

Comment: unfortunately, I still end up where I begin with this. The grid of buttons is still present.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated*:
I infer that `GameAreaWidgetContents` is a `QScrollArea`. To clear its layout manager, you can do:

```
delete ui->GameAreaWidgetContents->layout();
```

The vbox will no longer be the widget's layout manager and any nested children will be deleted automatically by the Qt parenting system.

From the [docs on `QWidget::setLayout()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout):

> If there already is a layout manager installed on this widget, QWidget won't let you install another. You must first delete the existing layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout() with the new layout.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work, I received the following: `QWidget::setLayout: Cannot set layout to 0`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've fixed this, This is less of a Qt issue, but more of a lack of clearing the `vector<vector<QPushButton*>> buttonGrid` object. It looked like the layout wasn't being cleared, because the additional `QPushButton` objects were being added onto the `vector<vector<QPushButton*>>` object.

It's a fairly rookie mistake on my behalf.

Comment: With dynamic layouts I generally don't store the widget pointers in a vector or list. Instead I just use findChildren<>().